# private key to wif - need help converting to base58encode (step 6 to step 7)

Tags: private-key, base58, wallet-import-format

I am trying to learn more about how bitcoin addresses are created. I am following along with the tutorial at https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format

I undertsand how they do the first six steps however I do not understand how to go from step 6 to step 7

they have `800C28FCA386C7A227600B2FE50B7CAE11EC86D3BF1FBE471BE89827E19D72AA1D507A5B8D`
and they get the private key of `5HueCGU8rMjxEXxiPuD5BDku4MkFqeZyd4dZ1jvhTVqvbTLvyTJ`

I have read from [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Base58Check_encoding) that I need to do put the version byte in front which is 00 so I have

```
00800C28FCA386C7A227600B2FE50B7CAE11EC86D3BF1FBE471BE89827E19D72AA1D507A5B8D
```

then I need to do sha256(sha256(result)) = 74944C34 (first 4 bytes)
then I have

```
00800C28FCA386C7A227600B2FE50B7CAE11EC86D3BF1FBE471BE89827E19D72AA1D507A5B8D74944C34
```

then I am running it through this test vb.net code (I will put it in a loop once I get it working)

```
Dim number As BigInteger = System.Numerics.BigInteger.Parse("00800C28FCA386C7A227600B2FE50B7CAE11EC86D3BF1FBE471BE89827E19D72AA1D507A5B8D74944C34", NumberStyles.HexNumber)


Dim count As BigInteger = number / 58
    Dim remainder As Integer = number Mod 58
    MessageBox.Show(count.ToString())
    MessageBox.Show(remainder.ToString())
    count = count / 58
    remainder = count Mod 58
    MessageBox.Show(count.ToString())
    MessageBox.Show(remainder.ToString())
    count = count / 58
    remainder = count Mod 58
    MessageBox.Show(count.ToString())
    MessageBox.Show(remainder.ToString())
```

for some reason the numbers are 48,37,3 but this does not line up with the chart on the second link and the answer which is `5HueCGU8rMjxEXxiPuD5BDku4MkFqeZyd4dZ1jvhTVqvbTLvyTJ`

can someone please show me what I am doing wrong and help me understand the base58encode?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Version byte `0` is for addresses, for an uncompressed private key you want `128`.

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Base58Check_encoding#Version_bytes

Comment: I thought I did add that. that is what the 80 is in the front of the hexadecimal

Comment: 0x00 or 0x80, not both. Your example has 0x0080.

Comment: I used http://convertxy.com/index.php/numberbases/ to try and convert it but it still does not give anything near that 5Hue. I also used the vb.net code and it does not work either?

Comment: See [this](http://gobittest.appspot.com/Address) great webapp